# iOS Swift - TableView data source - saving data when app close

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I'm working on an swift application that uses a TableView. It's cells are filled-up with data that comes from a remote server. That's how my app works now, but I want to change this mode because I'm sure that it's not the correct way to do things:

First: when the tableview did load, I call a function that get data (json) from server with this method:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
```

After that, I save my data as an object in NSUserDefaults. The object contains strings such as username, description, location, picture... etc. I know that this is not correct to store images in NSUserDefaults even if these images are not so big...

Second: I fill up table's cells with data obtained from NSUserDefauts, where I have stored my json data.

First of all I want to know how to auto append data to the table when the user hits the last cell of the table, like all apps that uses tableviews for fetching user posts...

In Instagram, after the you close the app, disconnect from the internet, and reenter the app, it will show you the first 10 cells from the last table you've seen before closing the app, so Instagram saves somehow, somewhere, maybe in coredata, data for the first 10 cells.

How do you suggest me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Question is not particular.....

Load Data error.

Or you fetch the result from coreData error?

CoreData can save View and some informations.

Post your code.

Comment: I need a suggestion how to save data that comes from the server. Now, I'm saving it using nsuserdefaults but I think this isn't correct.

Comment: save data from server is eazy.

Comment: 1. you can use NSURLCache for cache request. 2. you can use FMDB or coredata save the data 3. file 4. userdefault with some basic data. you can open the github and search 'cache' key word, you will find sth.